# Do villagers always sell first?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

From the minecraft wiki, I can see that each villager begins with one trading offer which must be accepted before it can trade more offers. In my test world, every villager I've clicked on has offered to sell me things (as in, asking for emeralds in exchange for goods). They are capable of buying things (asking for goods in exchange for emeralds); is there something in the algorithm that prevents their first offer from being a "buy" offer (so I can get emeralds to trade to other villagers) or do I just have bad luck?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, I loaded up [-671258039](http://www.minecraftseeds.info/2012/08/671258039.html), the first villager I clicked offered this trade:

[image]

You're just unlucky.

Comment: In my very brief experiment, roughly half of the trades were selling emeralds.

Comment: Hmm... I wandered through 2-3 villages. I guess the random number generator hates me.

Comment: @Yamikuronue it is possible, the RNG in mine loves winter, each world I create the initial spawn is in a snow biome. EACH. ONE.  Some RNGs just don't have much 'R' :P

Comment: @hammythepig http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: I prefer this version of the joke: http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/

Comment: Breed more villagers, or kill some and watch them make more.

Comment: @Broam pervert...

Comment: @hammythepig Are you specifying the seed?

Comment: @ChrisNava nope I just start a new world, no seed input. Its just sheer dumb luck